# Improving classification results with Weka J48 and Naive Bayes Multinomial classifiers

Tags: weka, bayesian, decision-tree

I have been using Weka’s J48 and Naive Bayes Multinomial (NBM) classifiers upon 
frequencies of keywords in RSS feeds to classify the feeds into target 
categories.

For example, one of my .arff files contains the following data extracts:

```
@attribute Keyword_1_nasa_Frequency numeric
@attribute Keyword_2_fish_Frequency numeric
@attribute Keyword_3_kill_Frequency numeric
@attribute Keyword_4_show_Frequency numeric
…
@attribute RSSFeedCategoryDescription {BFE,FCL,F,M, NCA, SNT,S}

@data
0,0,0,34,0,0,0,0,0,40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,BFE
0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,BFE
0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,BFE
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,BFE
…
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,FCL
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F
…
20,0,64,19,0,162,0,0,36,72,179,24,24,47,24,40,0,48,0,0,0,97,24,0,48,205,143,62,7
8,0,0,216,0,36,24,24,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,140,24,0,0,0,0,72,176,0,0,144,48,0,38,0,284,
221,72,0,72,0,SNT
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,SNT
0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,S
```

And so on: there’s a total of 570 rows where each one is contains with the 
frequency of a keyword in a feed for a day. In this case, there are 57 feeds for 
10 days giving a total of 570 records to be classified. Each keyword is prefixed 
with a surrogate number and postfixed with ‘Frequency’.

I am using 10 fold x validation for both the J48s and NBM classifiers on a 
'black box' basis. Other parameters used are also defaults, i.e. 0.25 confidence 
and min number of objects is 2 for the J48s.

So far, my classification rates for an instance of varying numbers of days, date 
ranges and actual keyword frequencies with both J28 and NBM results being 
consistent in the 50 - 60% range. But, I would like to improve this if possible.

I have reduced the decision tree confidence level, sometimes as low as 0.1 but 
the improvements are very marginal.

Can anyone suggest any other way of improving my results?

To give more information, the basic process here involves a diverse collection of RSS feeds where each one belongs to a single category.

For a given date range, e.g. 01 - 10 Sep 2011, the text of each feed's item elements are combined. The text is then validated to remove words with numbers, accents and so on, and stop words (a list of 500 stop words from MySQL is used). The remaining text is then indexed in Lucene to work out the most popular 64 words.

Each of these 64 words is then searched for in the description elements of the feeds for each day within the given date range. As part of this, the description text is also validated in the same way as the title text and again indexed by Lucene. So a popular keyword from the title such as 'declines' is stemmed to 'declin': then if any similar words are found in the description elements which also stem to 'declin', such as 'declined', the frequency for 'declin' is taken from Lucene's indexing of the word from the description elements.

The frequencies shown in the .arff file match on this basis, i.e. on the first line above, 'nasa', 'fish', 'kill' are not found in the description items of a particular feed in the BFE category for that day, but 'show' is found 34 times. Each line represents occurrences in the description items of a feed for a day for all 64 keywords.

So I think that the low frequencies are not due to stemming. Rather I see it as the inevitable result of some keywords being popular in feeds of one category, but which don't appear in other feeds at all. Hence the spareness shown in the results. Generic keywords may also be pertinent here as well.

The other possibilities are differences in the numbers of feeds per category where more feeds are in categories like NCA than S, or the keyword selection process itself is at fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention anything about [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_stem). In my opinion you could have better results if you were performing word stemming and the WEKA evaluation was based on the **keyword stems**.

For example let's suppose that your WEKA model is built given a keyword *surfing* and a new rss feed contains the word *surf*. There should be a match between these two words.

There are many free available stemmers for several languages.

For the English language some available options for stemming are:

- The [Porter's stemmer](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/)
- Stemming based on the [WordNet's](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) dictionary

In case you would like to perform stemming using the WordNet's dictionary, there are libraries & frameworks that perform integration with WordNet.

Below you can find some of them:

- MIT Java WordNet interface ([JWI](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/))
- [Rita](http://www.rednoise.org/rita/)
- Java WorNet Library ([JWNL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/))

**EDITED** after more information was provided

I believe that the keypoint in the specified case is the selection of the "most popular 64 words". The selected words or phrases should be keywords or keyphrases. So the challenge here is the keywords or keyphrases extraction.

There are several books, papers and algorithms written about keywords/keyphrases extraction. The university of Waikato has implemented in JAVA, a famous algorithm called [Keyword Extraction Algorithm (KEA)](http://www.nzdl.org/Kea/). KEA extracts keyphrases from text documents and can be either used for free indexing or for indexing with a controlled vocabulary. The implementation is distributed under the GNU General Public License.

Another issue that should be taken into consideration is the (Part of Speech)POS tagging. **Nouns contain more information** than the other POS tags. Therefore may you would have better results if you were checking the POS tag and the selected 64 words were mostly nouns.

In addition according to the Anette Hulth's published paper [Improved Automatic Keyword Extraction Given More Linguistic Knowledge](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/acl2003/emnlp/pdf/Hulth.pdf), her experiments showed that the keywords/keyphrases mostly have or are contained in one of the following five patterns:

- ADJECTIVE NOUN (singular or mass)
- NOUN NOUN (both sing. or mass)
- ADJECTIVE NOUN (plural)
- NOUN (sing. or mass) NOUN (pl.)
- NOUN (sing. or mass)

In conclusion a simple action that in my opinion could improve your results is to find the POS tag for each word and select mostly nouns in order to evaluate the new RSS feeds. You can use WordNet in order to find the POS tag for each word and as I mentioned above there are many libraries on the web that perform integration with the WordNet's dictionary. Of course stemming is also essential for the classification process and has to be maintained.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, the keywords are being stemmed prior to classification by Lucene's implementation of Porter.

Comment: Could you provide a high level description of the whole procedure? It will help us to have a better understanding of how your system works. The keywords are stemmed using Lucene's stemmer but what happens afterwards? Are the new rss feeds classified using the stems or not? Thanks

Comment: I've added a detailed description of the process and some thoughts of my own as to why the frequencies are low. Maybe I can't see the 'wood for the trees' at the moment.

Comment: OK, I understood the case. I will soon update the post with my thoughts.

Comment: I've made a slight change made to the definition of the process, to mention use of Lucene indexing the description items.

Comment: 'I believe that the keypoint in the specified case is the selection of the "most popular 64 words". The selected words or phrases should be keywords or keyphrases. So the challenge here is the keywords or keyphrases extraction.' At the moment, this is simply based upon frequency where the keywords are naive, i.e. unigrams regardless of whether they are nouns, verbs etc (ngrams will follow later). And that might well be the flaw as you suggest. I will look at the KEA. Thanks.

Comment: You can try KEA which is mostly an algorithm based on statistics or use a library which integrates with WordNet (JWI, Rita, JWNL) to find the POS tag and select nouns (more linguistic option). I'm glad I could help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off stemming altogether.  The Stanford Intro to IR authors [provide a rough justification](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/features-for-text-1.html) of why stemming hurts, and at the very least does not help, in text classification contexts.

I have tested stemming myself on a custom multinomial naive Bayes text classification tool (I get accuracies of 85%).  I tried the 3 Lucene stemmers available from org.apache.lucene.analysis.en version 4.4.0, which are EnglishMinimalStemFilter, KStemFilter and PorterStemFilter, plus no stemming, and I did the tests on small and larger training document corpora.  **Stemming significantly degraded classification accuracy when the training corpus was small, and left accuracy unchanged for the larger corpus**, which is consistent with the Intro to IR statements.

Some more things to try:

- Why only 64 words?  I would increase that number by a lot, but preferably you would not have a limit at all.
- Try [tf-idf (term frequency, inverse document frequency)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).  What you're using now is just tf.  If you multiply this by idf you can mitigate problems arising from common and uninformative words like "show".  This is especially important given that you're using so few top words.
- Increase the size of the training corpus.
- Try shingling to bi-grams, tri-grams, etc, and combinations of different [N-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) (you're now using just unigrams).

There's a bunch of other knobs you could turn, but I would start with these.  You should be able to do a lot better than 60%.  80% to 90% or better is common.